# Assigning values to a custom type after file read

Tags: c

Sorry if the question is kind of dumb, but I dont know much about C so im struggling with char pointers and such. Let me explain what I have.

cell.h

```
typedef struct{
    //Some things
    char value;
}Cell;
```

cell.c

```
#include "cell.h"
void cell_init(Cell cell, char value){
    cell.value = value;
}
```

board.h

```
typedef struct{
    //Some things
    Cell cells[5][5]
}Board;
```

board.c

```
#include "board.h"
#include "cell.h"
void board_init(Board* board){
    FILE* file;
    char* filename = "file.txt";
    char newLine[255];
    file = fopen(filename, "r");

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        char* line = fgets(newLine, sizeof(newLine),file);
        char* character = strtok(line, " ");
        int j = 0;
        while(character != NULL && j<5){
            cell_init(board->cells[i][j], *character); //This is surely wrong
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

main.c

```
#include "board.h"
int main(void){
    Board* board;
    board_init(board)
}
```

file.txt

```
5 7 2 5 2
2 1 5 6 1
2 4 7 4 3
2 3 5 6 5
2 3 5 3 5
```

Basically Im making a matrix of cells inside the board, reading a file and putting the data from the file inside each cell (Thats what I want it to do) but I keep getting segFault error (Surely is the `*character`).

Clearly Im doing things really wrong so, how can I get the values I get from the file into my cells? I get really lost with how pointers work for assigning values and such.

If more info is needed please ask.

Edit1: Added newLine

Edit2: Modified code to serve as error reproduction

Edit3: Wow, the problem was that I was passing a `Board*` to `board_init` when I should have passed the actual direction of the board (`&board`).

Comment: `cell_init(&board->cells[i][j], *character);` what's the `&` for? What is the declaration for `newLine`?

Comment: Im trying to send a `Cell*`, `board->[i][j]` is a Cell.
Maybe its `&(board[i][j])`? Sorry if this is really wrong

Comment: Ok, so, instead of using `Cell*` in `cell_init` args, should I use `Cell`? I tried that out but Im still getting segFault

Comment: `board->cells[i][j]` is the character within the original `Cell cells[5][5]`, so passing the address of that should be fine. The problem would seem to be elsewhere, can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sure!, ill update with MCVE

Comment: Well, with Edit3 i fixed that issue. Im so dumb. Problem is that im getting junk inside each Cell now (Probably has to do with the `(*character)` at `cell_init`)

Comment: You don't need to annotate the edits into the question. I take you are familiar to Reddit. But unlike that site, Stack Overflow lets you see the edit history. Just keep the last version.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have figured out things are a mess... The mess is complicated by your separation of everything in what would be a simple example into separate files (which is fine, but your attention is constantly shifting between files requiring you to keep things straight between files that would otherwise be immediately apparent if everything was in the same source file)

For every header file, you need to include *header-guards* to prevent the header from being included multiple times if used is more that one file, e.g. for `cell.h`:

```
/* protect every header with header-guards */
#ifndef CELL_H
#define CELL_H  1

/* your header content goes here! */

#endif
```

Now the header is included only if `CELL_H` is not previously defined.

Let's look at the content your `cell.h` requires here. You must include all information needed by `cell.c` and you must include all function *declarations* that will be available to files that include `cell.h` in the header, e.g.:

```
/* protect every header with header-guards */
#ifndef CELL_H
#define CELL_H  1

typedef struct {
    //Some things
    char value;
} Cell;

/* declare function prototypes in header */
void cell_init (Cell *cell, char value);

#endif
```

(**note:** above `cell_init` must take a pointer to `cell`, e.g. `Cell *cell` to allow you to update the memory at that address with the new value instead of updating the memory for a local copy of `cell` if passed as type `Cell` instead of `Cell*`)

Your `cell.c` simply *defines* the functions with *declarations* in `cell.h` and implements any additional logic needed, e.g.

```
#include "cell.h"

/* must take pointer to cell to update memory at that address in funciton */
void cell_init (Cell *cell, char value)
{
    cell->value = value;
}
```

Your `board.h` had further problems due to the failure to `#include` the system header files required by the functions used in `board.c`. For example you need `stdio.h` for `fgets()` and `string.h` for `strtok()`. You further should not use *magic-numbers* like `5` in your code. If you need a constant, `#define` one. You also fail to include the local header `cell.h` so the type `Cell` is unknown in `board.h` and `board.c`.

To correct the issues in `board.h` you could do:

```
/* protect every header with header-guards */
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H  1

#include <stdio.h>  /* include system headers required by board.c */
#include <string.h>

#include "cell.h"   /* include local headers required by board.c */

#define BOARDSZ 5   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

typedef struct {
    //Some things
    Cell cells[BOARDSZ][BOARDSZ];   /* use constants, not magic-numbers */
} Board;

/* declare function prototypes in header */
int board_init (Board *board, FILE *file);

#endif
```

(**note:** how the file has been opened in the calling function (`main()` here) and validated that it is open for reading and passed as a parameter to `board_init`. This is good practice, if you cannot open the file in the caller, there is no need to call `board_init`)

In `board.c` you were only calling `strtok` once to get teh first token. You must call `strtok` for every column in your file (`BOARDSZ` of them). **NOTE:** all subsequent calls to `strtok` use `NULL` as the first parameter instead of the original pointer. As mentioned above, you must pass the address of `cells[i][j]` to the `cell_init` function, so your call will be:

```
            cell_init (&board->cells[i][j], *token);
```

(where I use `token` instead of `line` as `strtok` splits a line into tokens)

You also must validate that you read `BOARDSZ` values for per-row, and `BOARDSZ` rows of values. Since you take input in `board_init` you need to choose a meaningful return type other than `void` that can indicate the *success* or *failure* of `board_init`. Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include "cell.h"
#include "board.h"

int board_init (Board *board, FILE *file)
{
    char newline[255];  /* storage for line */
    int i = 0;          /* required after loop to validate no. of rows */

    for (; i < BOARDSZ; i++) {  /* loop for BOARDSZ lines */
        /* read line into newline, validate */
        if (fgets (newline, sizeof(newline),file) == NULL)
            return 0;

        char *token = strtok (newline, " \n");  /* get first token */
        int j = 0;      /* required after loop to validate columns */

        while (token != NULL && j < BOARDSZ){   /* while token loop BOARDSZ */
            /* initialize cell[i][j].value passing pointer to cells[i][j] */
            cell_init (&board->cells[i][j], *token);
            j++;                                /* increment columns */
            token = strtok (NULL, " \n");       /* get next token */
        }

        if (j < BOARDSZ)    /* validate BOARDSZ columns per-row */
            return 0;
    }
    if (i < BOARDSZ)        /* validate BOARDSZ rows */
        return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Finally `board` must have VALID storage (either declared with *automatic storage* or allocated with `malloc/calloc/realloc`). Your current `Board *board` does nothing but declare an *uninitialized pointer*. The rest of `main.c` simply opens the file, validates it is open for reading, and then calls `board_init` passing the *address of* board (so you pass a pointer-to `board`) along with the open file stream. You then validate `board_init` succeeds in filling all rows and columns before making use of the values. (here they are simply output again)

Your `main.c` could be:

```
#include "board.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    Board board;    /* board must have valid memory */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    if (!board_init (&board, fp)) { /* validate board_init succeeds */
        fputs ("error: board_init failed.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < BOARDSZ; i++) {         /* loop over rows */
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARDSZ; j++) {     /* loop over cols */
            if (j)                              /* if not 1st, add space */
                putchar (' ');
            putchar (board.cells[i][j].value);  /* output cells[i][j].value */
        }
        putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */
    }
}
```

**Compiling With Warnings Enabled**

Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles cleanly without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string (also consider adding `-Wshadow` to warn on shadowed variables). For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. Read and understand each warning -- then go fix it. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn a lot by listening to what your compiler is telling you.

For example:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -Ofast board.c cell.c -o bin/main main.c
```

**Example Use/Output**

Just pass the filename to read as the first argument to your program (or read from `stdin` by default if no argument is given), e.g.

```
$ ./bin/main file.txt
5 7 2 5 2
2 1 5 6 1
2 4 7 4 3
2 3 5 6 5
2 3 5 3 5
```

That's it. You were a bit off and missing a number of critical elements in your code -- but, your call to `cell_init` was basically correct.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.